# how can I get animation when going to previous view

Tags: iphone, animation

i have used viewcontroller with multiple view.
when i go back to previous, there is no animation
i have tried by below lines of code ,

```
-(IBAction)goback
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
 [self.view removeFromSuperview]; 
 [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't animate a method call. You can only animate properties of the view such as frame, size, alpha etc. `removeFromSuperview` isn't a property, it is a method that simply finds the superview and removes the originating view from the array of subviews.

You need to run the animation and then send `removeFromSuperview` when the animation completes.

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];    
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: this is true answer for multiview application

Comment: @jaydp: As it is your question, why not vote it as the answer if it is correct?